# (Android) How to catch a "ring" event?

Tags: android

I'm clearly a newb, and I was wondering if anyone knows how I can detect a "ring" event on my cellphone through the android sdk?  Generally I want to do something with the phone when it begins ringing!  Any thoughts?

If you want to simply point me to a page in the api documents that would be a good answer for me, I just don't know how to start my research!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this site here: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/phonecalls.html