# is it possible to write an app that is invoked by the phone ringing?

Tags: android

I'm guessing the answer is no, but just in case, I'm curious if there's any way to write a receiver that would launch an app when the phone starts to receive a call.  Even something as simple as a dialog activity that says "your phone is ringing". Or is the phone always going to suppress any other app that's trying to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register a `BroadcastReceiver` to 'listen' for...

```
TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED
```

You can then check `EXTRA_STATE` for `CALL_STATE_RINGING`.

However, I'm not sure why you would want to 'launch an app'. You say...

> Even something as simple as a dialog activity that says "your phone is ringing".

My phone already tells me when my phone is ringing - I get custom ringtones depending on who is calling me and I get to see their picture too. I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question might have already been asked here on SO:
[Catch a Ring event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433337/android-how-to-catch-a-ring-event)

First, I'm not an Android programmer, but I'm pretty sure you can do what you are asking.

Essentially the Android OS is running the device and processing incoming calls (smart phones are more computer than phone nowadays).  I hypothesize that embedded in the OS is a series of "events" or "state changes/flags" that the OS uses to interrupt other running programs, that switches the focus to the phone application when the hardware notices an incoming call.

I believe that detecting and reacting to the event is possible, as the phone is running daemon processes in the background while the phone call is happening.  I read most of the blog entry that this other SO post links to, and it looks like some moderately complex stuff, but not impossible.

Good luck to you!

Comment: I just looked at the blog entry linked in the answer to the SO question you linked to in your answer. The person who wrote the blog refers to a `BroadcastReceiver` (correct) as an 'IntentReceiver' (WRONG). Not only that but the blog entry was written over 4 years ago and the author seems more concerned about the fact the emulator kept crashing. Not the best example of good programming I've seen.

Comment: @MisterSquonk thanks for the info.  I was more concerned with the original posters question of whether or not it is possible.  It seems that it is possible.  I've never done any Android programming, so I'll have to take your word for it.